# Ubuntu will not boot after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I upgraded from 10.24 to the next version and now during boot I see the Ubuntu screen briefly but after that the screen goes black.

I can get to the recovery mode but I don't know what to do. I know there similar questions online but they all seem different.

Is there a way to fix this problem or do I have to reinstall and lose all existing data?

---

**EDIT**

For anyone who is having the same problem see [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192528)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the installation medium, `i.e.` the USB key or the CD from which you installed Ubuntu? If so, the problem might be easily solved. Boot from the installation medium, choose `Try Ubuntu without installing it`, then open a terminal and install Boot-Repair. You will find [the instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to do that. The very same page contains also the instructions on how to run Boot-Repair. The standard options are perfectly fine, they are sufficient to solve most problems. Should this fail, at the end of the page you are told how to provide more info for the guy who developed Boot-Repair, who is kind enough to answer queries on the Ubuntu forum.

Just one caveat: no software can be **permanently** installed on a live distro, so that, if for any reason you will have to do so once again, you will have to re-install Boot-Repair as if it had never been installed before.

Edit:

your pastebin file says that SecureBoot may be enabled. This means you have to go into your Bios and disable SecureBoot.

Comment: How do I boot from the USB? I have the USB stick plugged and I turn on the computer but it takes me to GNU GRUB screen. When I select "Ubuntu" it does not boot from the USB but goes to the black screen. Thanks.

Comment: You have to enter your BIOS and select the USB as the first medium to boot from, before CD or HDD. To enter your BIOS, you hit a specific button immediately after power up. The specific button is pc-dependent, it can be anything from Escape to F1 to F12, you will have to try it.

Comment: I tried to follow instructions here but I don't see "USB HDD" as in the 3rd step and cannot log in from USB http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/40334-booting-modern-samsung-laptop-from-usb-drive

Comment: The writing `USB HDD` is specific to the pc and its BIOS. In my pc, it says: removable media, instead of USB

Comment: Ok. I ran the boot repair as instructed but I still get the black screen. I guess now I will have to ask a question in the forums. This is the url from boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6541631/

Comment: @Zeynel Please see the edit to my answer

Comment: Ok, i disabled. Secure Boot but I still get the same black screen. I will just go ahead and reinstall and lose all data.

Comment: I made some progress. I added nomodeset to GRUB now I don't get the black screen but it stooped loading on the ubuntu screen. Any idea what I am doong wrong?

Comment: @Zeynel Can you log into tty1? To do so, when boot stops, hit simultaneously Ctrl+Alt+F1. You should see a login prompt. Please tell me whether you can do this.

Comment: I was able to log into tty1 when I tried to boot from grub. After I logged in I tried the instructions here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192528 and that fixed the problem. Do you have the same (or similar) suggestions? If so can you add to the answer so that we can have a good answer here too. Thanks.